# help clearing the doubt about column space

Tags: linear-algebra

**it is an easy one** but I don't have anyone else to ask rather than stack exchange 
**doubt** is it true that if $b\in \mathbb{R^{n}}$ such that $b\in col(A)$ where $A$ is n×m matrix then there exist unique real numbers $a_{1},\dots,a_n$ s.t. $b=a_{1}A_{1}+\dots+a_{n}A_{n}$ where $A_{1},\dots,A_n$ are column vectors of $A$ I don't know how to prove these things but i don't need a proof. can you tell me that is it true or false and where I can start  with if want to prove or disprove it.

Comment: The $a_i$ need not be unique (consider the zero matrix), but they exist, by definition of $col(A).$

Comment: what if it's given matrix is non zero

Comment: They could still not be unique if the column vectors are linearly dependant, which is equivalent to $rank(A)<m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column space of a matrix is the set of all linear combinations of its column vectors, so $b \in \mathrm{col}(A) =a_{1}A_{1}+\dots+a_{n}A_{n}$ for some $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ by definition.  If you've come across the idea of linear independence, you'll know that $b$ can be expressed in the form uniquely iff $\left\{A_1,\dots,A_n\right\}$ is a linearly independent set.

To disprove the statement, you can just supply a counter-example, e.g.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$, $b=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=0\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}+2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: thanks @Frentos and example is helpful